# Directive to wrap html element in hyperlink

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'd like to write own directive which can wrap any html element in hyperlink using the passed parameter, so for example:

```
<button myDirective="parameter">...</button>
```

will have following effect

```
<a href="url/parameter"><button>...</button></a>
```

I'm beginner in AngularJS. Unfortunately I didn't find any helpful tutorial for making this in **typescript**.

I created sth like that:

```
export default class LinksHelperDirective implements ng.IDirective {
public static Name = "kb-link";
public restrict = "A";
public urlTemplate = "";

constructor(private readonly $parse: ng.IParseService) {
}

public static Factory() : any {
    const directive = ($parse: ng.IParseService) => {
        return new LinksHelperDirective($parse);
    };

    directive["$inject"] = ["$parse"];
    return directive;
}

link = (scope: ng.IScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes,
    ngModel: ng.INgModelController) => {
    const linkId = this.$parse(attrs["kb-link"])(scope);
    const wrapper = angular.element('<a href="https://support/' + linkId + '"></a>');
    element.wrap(wrapper);
};
```

}

But unfortunately it doesn't work... even constructor is not called. I registered directive in index file like below:

```
module.directive(LinksHelperDirective.Name, LinksHelperDirective.Factory(), ["$parse"]);
```

and in html file:

```
<button kb-link="1234">Help</button>
```

Anybody knows what's wrong with that?

Comment: is directive necessary? why not `<a type="button" href="..."> ... </a>` ?

Comment: Yes, it's necessary. I'd like to have possibility to wrap any element. It looks better in code in my mind and it's easier to maintenance so directive is right choice.

Comment: I would go for a component with content transclusion. it's cleaner

Comment: @toskv I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: @PiotrP here is [content wrapping example](http://plnkr.co/edit/PUUJ6Y2vP1tCOMOWGYx2?p=preview) and [content transclusion example](http://embed.plnkr.co/FeXrKv1lh4qlTtNqilPi/)

Comment: @toskv I find content wrapping example in typescript (as I add) cleaner than using transclusion, I mean it looks better in html files

Comment: it might be more minimal, but it also obscures the structure of generated html, it will mislead people seeing it used in the future. That however is of course just my opinion and you are free to ignore it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ng-transclude` directive for that

```
class WrapDirective {
  restrict = 'E';
  transclude = true;
  scope = { someLink: '<' };
  template: '<a ng-href="url/{{ someLink }}"><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></a>';
}
```

But you need to wrap your element like `<wrap-directive some-link="$ctrl.link"><button>...</wrap-directive>`